# Get-PsDrive Description not showing drive name

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the location of a usb named `Foobar`.

Running `(Get-PsDrive -Name D).Description` works in `Powershell ISE` but not in `Powershell`.

When running in `Powershell ISE` the result is `Foobar`
When running in `Powershell` I get nothing back (empty string)

What is the difference when running the same command in ISE and in the normal powershell?
Also is it possible to get a drive location reliably by the name/label of the device?

Comment: It seems more reliable to use `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk) | Where VolumeName -eq "Foobar" | Select-Object DeviceID` but is it?

Comment: There shouldn't really be any difference (and both return Description for me without issue). Does `$PSVersion` output identical results in both places?

Comment: @PMental Thanks. Yes there is a difference. In ISE I get back `24` and in powershell I get nothing back (empty string if anything). Just to add more details. ISE is located in `%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe` and Powershell is located in `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` both are run without running as admin

Comment: I suspect this is some configuration setting that causes this issue, but I have not been able to find the source.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, I tested using this script:

```
clear-host
$x = Get-Psdrive | Where-object Name -like "?"
ForEach ($drv in $x) {
  "$($drv.name) : $($drv.Description)"
}
```

I got the following result on 5.1 ISE 5.1.18362.1171 & CMD  5.1.18362.1171 and also on PS7 7.0.0 (all 64 Bit):
[image]
Since you're checking for D, I'm assuming it is a CD drive. Thus, it appears to be normal behavior? Not sure why you got different results.

Comment: Sorry nope, it is a usb drive. I still havent figured why it works in ISE and not PS for me. Moved on to using `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk)` to get the drive label